# Replace all matches using re.findall()

Tags: python, regex

Using `re.findall()` I've managed to get return multiple matches of a regex in a string. However my object returned is a list of matches within the string. This is not what I want.

What I want is to replace all matches with something else. I've tried to use similar syntax as you would use in re.sub to do this as so:

```
import json
import re

regex = re.compile('([a-zA-Z]\"[a-zA-Z])', re.S)

filepath = "C:\\Python27\\Customer Stuff\\Austin Tweets.txt"

f = open(filepath, 'r')
myfile = re.findall(regex, '([a-zA-Z]\%[a-zA-Z])', f.read())
print myfile
```

However, this creates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Customer Stuff/Austin's Script.py", line 9, in <module>
    myfile = re.findall(regex, '([a-zA-Z]\%[a-zA-Z])', f.read())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 229, in _compile
    bypass_cache = flags & DEBUG
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

Can anyone assist me within the last bit of syntax I need to replace all matches with something else within the original Python object?

**EDIT:**

In line with comments and answers received, here is me trying to sub one regex with another:

```
import json
import re

regex = re.compile('([a-zA-Z]\"[a-zA-Z])', re.S)
regex2 = re.compile('([a-zA-Z]%[a-zA-Z])', re.S)

filepath = "C:\\Python27\\Customer Stuff\\Austin Tweets.txt"

f = open(filepath, 'r')
myfile = f.read()
myfile2 = re.sub(regex, regex2, myfile)
print myfile
```

This now produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Customer Stuff/Austin's Script.py", line 11, in <module>
    myfile2 = re.sub(regex, regex2, myfile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 273, in _subx
    template = _compile_repl(template, pattern)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 258, in _compile_repl
    p = sre_parse.parse_template(repl, pattern)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sre_parse.py", line 706, in parse_template
    s = Tokenizer(source)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sre_parse.py", line 181, in __init__
    self.__next()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sre_parse.py", line 183, in __next
    if self.index >= len(self.string):
TypeError: object of type '_sre.SRE_Pattern' has no len()
```

Comment: Use `re.sub` if you want to replace the matches.

Comment: how and where would I use re.sub() though? if you try using it on the object you created from re.findall() this is a list of matches, not the original object.

Comment: what are you trying to replace it with?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham basically i have a list of lists that's full of none JSON friendly things in a text file that I need to read in as a list of lists from the text file. so i'm trying to replace the pattern with something that JSON will accept.

Comment: can you add a snippet of the strings because it is not totally clear what you actually want to do

Comment: @PadraicCunningham please see my edited question. thanks

Comment: You are passing a compiled regex as the second arg to sub which should be what you want replace any matches with i.e a string.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the difficulty there is I only want to replace part of the regex. i dont want to replace 'e"f' with '%' for a example. i would want the replacement to be 'e%f', so im not sure how to do that with re.sub(). i hope that makes sense. thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
import re

regex = re.compile('([a-zA-Z]\"[a-zA-Z])', re.S)
myfile =  'foo"s bar'
myfile2 = regex.sub(lambda m: m.group().replace('"',"%",1), myfile)
print(myfile2)
```

Comment: that worked great, thanks. could you briefly talk me through what the lambda line is doing though, so i know for future reference?

Comment: @gdogg371, m is  a match object so we just use .group to get the matched substring i.e `o"s` in our example and we then replace the double quote with the percent sign

Comment: and the lamda is just allowing us to use an unassigned function within the re.sub logic?

Comment: @gdogg371, exactly,  what happens in the lambda is what is going to be replace in our string

Comment: No worries, no doubt there is probably a better was as regex is not my strong point but this should work fine for your needs

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to replace a quotation mark between two characters with an percent sign between those characters.

There are several ways to do this with `re.sub` (`re.findall` doesn't do replacements at all, so your initial attemps were always doomed to fail).

An easy approach would be to change your pattern to group the letters separately, and then use a replacement string that includes backreferences:

```
pattern = re.compile('([a-zA-Z])\"([a-zA-Z])', re.S)
re.sub(pattern, r'\1%\2', text)
```

Another option would be to use a replacement function instead of a replacement string. The function will be called with a `match` object for each match found in the text, and its return value is the replacement:

```
pattern = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]\"[a-zA-Z]', re.S)
re.sub(pattern, lambda match: "{0}%{2}".format(*match.group()), text)
```

(There are probably lots of other ways of implementing the lambda function. I like string formatting.)

However, probably the best approach is to use a lookahead and a lookbehind in your pattern to make sure your quotation mark is between letters without actually matching those letters. This lets you use the trivial string `'%'` as the replacement:

```
pattern = re.compile('(?<=[a-zA-Z])\"(?=[a-zA-Z])', re.S)
re.sub(pattern, '%', text)
```

This does have very slightly different semantics than the other versions. A text like `'a"b"c'` will have both quotation marks replaced, while the previous codes would only replace the first one. Hopefully this is an improvement!

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in comment, use [`re.sub()`](http://devdocs.io/python/library/re#re.sub):

```
myfile = re.sub(regex, replacement, f.read())
```

where, replacement is the string your matches will be substituted with.

Comment: Let's say that my regular expression is r"^in". For the string "within", using `sub` is not the same as match and replace since `sub` would replace also the "in" in "wihin", that does not match the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

I find it clearer to use a function to do this type of substitution rather than a lambda. It makes it easy to perform any number of transformations on the matched text prior to replacing the text:

```
import re

def replace_double_quote(match):
    text = match.group()
    return text.replace('"', '%')

regex = re.compile('([a-zA-Z]\"[a-zA-Z])')
myfile = 'foo"s bar and bar"s foo'
regex.sub(replace_double_quote, myfile)
```

This returns `foo%s bar and bar%s foo`. Note that it replaces all matches.