# regex substitute every appearance of a capture group with another capture group

Tags: python, regex

I am reformatting a large set of sales data.

Each sale shows the name of the item, number of items being sold, and the price rounded to the nearest whole number.

**1 bag of 20 Apples sold for $3:**
`Apple/,20,3,`

If more than one sale occurs, the sales data replaces the item name for every result after the first one.

**4 bags of 20 Apples sold for $3:** `Apple/,20,3%20,3%20,3%20,3,`

I need to display the item name for every sale instead of the % sign

**Desired Result**: `Apple/,20,3,Apple/,20,3,Apple/,20,3,Apple/,20,3,`

**So Far:**
I have been banging my head against this for six hours, and tried several approaches.

I had thought running a regex substitution using the re module in python using the expression `([A-Za-z]+\/)?(\%)?(\d+\,\d+\,)`
would produce the needed result after substituting `\1\3` for the full match, however this only applies the first capture group to the beginning of all consecutive matches of the third capture group.

`Apple/,20,3,20,3,20,3,20,3,`

I suspect this has to do with the difference between capture groups and capture objects, but am stuck trying to find a way to append the first capture group to each appearance of a capture object for a given capture group (eg, append capture group 1 to the beginning of every match for capture group 3.)

To get around this, I tried a modified version of the answer for: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670413/replace-all-matches-using-re-findall`

```
import re

regex = re.compile('([A-Za-z]+\/)?(\%)?(\d+\,\d+\,)', re.S)
itemsales =  'Apple/20,3,%20,3,%20,3,%20,3,'
sales_fixed = regex.sub(lambda m: m.group().replace('%',"\1",1), myfile)
print(sales_fixed)
```

and this returns the exact same result of

```
Apple/,20,3,20,3,20,3,20,3,
```

which I suspect may be a result of incorrectly referencing my capture group in the substitution

How can I replace the percent signs with the product name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern that you tried only matches the last part because the first 2 parts are optional, and it can match the `%` and `20,3,` part

The match the format described in the question, you could repeat the part matching the digits comma digits that is followed by a `%` after matching `Apple/` first in group 1.

Then in the replacement, use capture group 1 between 2 comma's `x.group(1)`

A few notes about the code and the pattern:

- You don't have to use `re.S` as there are no dots in the pattern that have to match a newline.
- You don't have to escape the `,` `/` and `%`
- There are 2 different strings used in the description of the question, and in the example code.

The pattern could look like:

```
\b([A-Za-z]+/),(?:\d+,\d+%)+
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Za-z]+/` Match 1+ times a char in the ranges A-Z a-z
- `)` Close group 1
- `,(?:\d+,\d+%)+` Match a comma, and repeat 1+ times matching 1+ digits, a comma and again 1+ digits

For example

```
import re

pattern = r"\b([A-Za-z]+/),(?:\d+,\d+%)+"
itemsales = "Apple/,20,3%20,3%20,3%20,3,"

sales_fixed = re.sub(
    pattern,
    lambda x: x.group().replace('%', ",{0},".format(x.group(1))),
    itemsales
)

print(sales_fixed)
```

Output

```
Apple/,20,3,Apple/,20,3,Apple/,20,3,Apple/,20,3,
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0nYwTV/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Q3LLur)

Answer (score 2):

Let us fix your code

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b([A-Za-z]+/)\S+', re.S)
sales_fixed = regex.sub(lambda m: m.group().replace('%', f',{m.group(1)},'), itemsales)
```

---

```
>>> sales_fixed

Apple/,20,3,Apple/,20,3,Apple/,20,3,Apple/,20,3,
```

**Regex details:**

- `\b` : assert position at a word boundary
- `([A-Za-z]+/)` : First capturing group

  - `[A-Za-z]+` : Matches any character in the list one or more times
  - `/` : Matches the character `/` literally
- `\S+` : Matches any non-whitespace character one or more times

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following, written and tested in Python3.6. Simple explanation would be: Creating a variable named `s` which has all the values shown by OP in it, then using `re` library of python here. Using `re.sub` to perform substitution here; create var which has value of captured group of getting value, finally performing substitution on
actual variable s.

```
import re
s="Apple/,20,3%20,3%20,3%20,3,"
var=re.sub('^([A-Za-z]+/).*', r"\1", s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
re.sub('%(\d+)', r','+var+',\g<1>', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
'Apple/,20,3,Apple/,20,3,Apple/,20,3,Apple/,20,3,'
```